# LTSpice - varistor component

Tags: ltspice, education

What is the constitutive relashionship between current and voltage of a varistor in LTSpice? For example, if I set the control voltage V=1V and Rclamp=2, what is the formula to evaluate the resistance of varistor? I tried to do this simulation (I used a 10V voltage source in serie with R1=1 and a varistor), but the result it's strange for me. The current on R1 is 3A, \$V(R1)=R1\cdot I(R1)=1\cdot3=3V\$, but the resistance of varistor is not Rclamp=2 (is 7/3=2.3).
Thank you very much.

Comment: Why don't you plot the current when the applied voltage is a ramp - this seems likely to give you what you want.

Answer (score 1):

If you read in the LTspice manual, you'll see that it says it's breakdown voltage is set by the voltage applied at its control terminals. The voltage can be of any sign, any polarity (it counts as `abs(V(ctl))`), and the calculation is like this: if your applied voltage is `10V`, the series resistance is `1 Ohm`, `Rclamp=1` and the control voltage is `1V` (I presume), then the varistor will breakdown at `1V` (the controlling voltage), meaning from the total of `10V` you'll have `10-1=9V` which, divided by the total resistance of `3 Ohms` results in `3A`. If your source voltage is `7V`, series resistance is `2 Ohms`, `Rclamp=1.5` and controlling voltage `3V` => `(7-3)/(2.5+1.5)=4/4=1A`.